# How to write xpath div class containing <a> tag and <href> tag

Tags: python, xpath

What's the xpath for div class containing and  and href tag containing text ?

```html
<div class="xxx">
    <a href="www.xxxx" target="blank">pppp</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide any code sample of what you have already done.

Comment: Also there's a typing error in your question which makes it unclear what the `div` needs to contain; please fix.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here is the xpath you are looking for.

```
//div[contains(@class,'xx)]/a[contains(@href,'xxx')]
```

Replace xx and xxx with the values from your elements.